# In the story, why wasn't Takuma able to shoot fireballs for a while?

Tags: the-king-of-fighters

In the 2002 game, perhaps since 2001, Takuma mysteriously isn't able to shoot fireballs anymore and his moveset drastically changed. After this, he seemed to be absent from the storyline for a while until the return in XIII with all of his abilities.

Is there a lore reason he was unable to shoot fireballs during that period of time?

Comment: I'm aksing this question from the game storyline/plot perspective, not game development. The way you edited it actually makes it seem innapropiate, though.

Comment: lore questions are sometimes a touchy subject. If you ask for lore-specific answers, it's on-topic. If you ask the same question but don't specify you want lore only, it will likely be construed as questioning developer intent.

Comment: Well, it's specified heavily now